# dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to build a seaborn plot but my time data in my pandas dataframe is type timedelta64 and trying to convert to datetime 64 gives me the following error.  I've tried many things but stumped to what I doing wrong...

```
dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]
```

this is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8


#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import os, shutil, glob, time, subprocess, re, sys, sqlite3, logging, smtplib
from datetime import timedelta
import pymysql
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#function to load db connection
def get_user_data():
    user_data = {}
    with open("new_user_data.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (field, val) = line.split()
            user_data[field] = val
    return user_data

user_data=get_user_data()

mysql_host = user_data['mysql_host']
mysql_user = user_data['mysql_user']
mysql_password = user_data['mysql_password']
mysql_database = user_data['mysql_database']

# Connect to SQL db
db = pymysql.connect(host=mysql_host, user=mysql_user, password=mysql_password, database=mysql_database)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("USE hms")

# Build query
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT sensor_id, label, temp, time, date FROM temps INNER JOIN sensors USING (sensor_id) where label="basement one"and date="2022-01-28"''', db)

# build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['sensor_id', 'label', 'temp', 'time','date'])

print(df)
print(type(df))
print (df.time.dtype) # output is "timedelta64[ns]""
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

g=sns.lineplot(x='time', y='temp', data=df,color="darkblue")
g.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%I'))
g.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Temperature')
```

this is the full error output from my jupyter notebook:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-535ace5a9503> in <module>
      8 #df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.time
      9 print (df.time.dtype)
---> 10 df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
     11 

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    803             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    804         else:
--> 805             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    806             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    807     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    375     orig_arg = arg
    376     try:
--> 377         arg, _ = maybe_convert_dtype(arg, copy=False)
    378     except TypeError:
    379         if errors == "coerce":

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in maybe_convert_dtype(data, copy)
   2147     elif is_timedelta64_dtype(data.dtype) or is_bool_dtype(data.dtype):
   2148         # GH#29794 enforcing deprecation introduced in GH#23539
-> 2149         raise TypeError(f"dtype {data.dtype} cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]")
   2150     elif is_period_dtype(data.dtype):
   2151         # Note: without explicitly raising here, PeriodIndex

TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]
```

this is my dataframe:

```
           sensor_id         label  temp            time        date
0    28-000005c62a30  basement one  65.6 0 days 15:27:41  2022-01-28
1    28-000005c62a30  basement one  65.6 0 days 15:29:23  2022-01-28
2    28-000005c62a30  basement one  65.6 0 days 15:31:04  2022-01-28
3    28-000005c62a30  basement one  65.5 0 days 15:32:46  2022-01-28
4    28-000005c62a30  basement one  65.6 0 days 15:34:27  2022-01-28
..               ...           ...   ...             ...         ...
297  28-000005c62a30  basement one  64.3 0 days 23:51:53  2022-01-28
298  28-000005c62a30  basement one  64.3 0 days 23:53:35  2022-01-28
299  28-000005c62a30  basement one  64.2 0 days 23:55:17  2022-01-28
300  28-000005c62a30  basement one  64.3 0 days 23:56:59  2022-01-28
301  28-000005c62a30  basement one  64.3 0 days 23:58:40  2022-01-28

[302 rows x 5 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a standalone time cannot be a `datetime` - it doesn't have a date - so pandas imports it as a `timedelta`.  The easy solution is to preprocess the file by combining the `date` and `time` columns together into one ("2022-01-28 15:31:04").  Pandas can import that directly to a `datetime`.

Comment: ok, I'll try that.  I just switched database types (was using cloudant, now mysql) data structure was same and this had worked in the past {df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)}. I thought that would work same, any way @Tim-Roberts thank you

Comment: You can use datetime.fromisoformat() than pd.to_datetime, then you can convert freely using .hour, or .minute

Comment: so the other issue was the data type in mysql database was time for my time column and data for the date column, once i changed that to varchar(20) i was able to use pd.to_datetime..