# ERROR using eval: "unknown type timedelta64[ns]" -- Python

Tags: python

I am trying to substract date time rows using "eval" using the following code:

```
delay = (
    dataset
    .query("INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC == '111 - Building fire'")
    .eval("ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME - INCIDENT_DATE_TIME")
    .divide(pd.Timedelta("1m"))
)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: unknown type timedelta64[ns]
```

Please find the dataset information below:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1736391 entries, 0 to 1736390
Data columns (total 24 columns):
 #   Column                        Dtype         
---  ------                        -----         
 0   IM_INCIDENT_KEY               object        
 1   FIRE_BOX                      object        
 2   INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC            object        
 3   INCIDENT_DATE_TIME            datetime64[ns]
 4   ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME             datetime64[ns]
 5   UNITS_ONSCENE                 float64       
 6   LAST_UNIT_CLEARED_DATE_TIME   object        
 7   HIGHEST_LEVEL_DESC            object        
 8   TOTAL_INCIDENT_DURATION       float64       
 9   ACTION_TAKEN1_DESC            object        
 10  ACTION_TAKEN2_DESC            object        
 11  ACTION_TAKEN3_DESC            object        
 12  PROPERTY_USE_DESC             object        
 13  STREET_HIGHWAY                object        
 14  ZIP_CODE                      object        
 15  BOROUGH_DESC                  object        
 16  FLOOR                         object        
 17  CO_DETECTOR_PRESENT_DESC      object        
 18  FIRE_ORIGIN_BELOW_GRADE_FLAG  float64       
 19  STORY_FIRE_ORIGIN_COUNT       float64       
 20  FIRE_SPREAD_DESC              object        
 21  DETECTOR_PRESENCE_DESC        object        
 22  AES_PRESENCE_DESC             object        
 23  STANDPIPE_SYS_PRESENT_FLAG    float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(5), object(17)
memory usage: 317.9+ MB
```

Above the dataset description / info. I am trying to subtract data from INCIDENT_DATE_TIME and ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME

Comment: What type is `dataset`? What does it contain?

Comment: Please find edits to the question including the dataset info

Comment: @Grismar, looks like a pandas query... maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911227/dtype-timedelta64ns-cannot-be-converted-to-datetime64ns) will help. 

edit: try converting the problematic column to datetime with `pd.to_datetime()` -- [docs ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html)

Comment: This is what I did one step before, I have used pd.to_datetime() to convert it to datetime, and looking at the dataset info before running the eval query, it can be seen that the data type of both columns is datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error when trying to use `eval`. Maybe you can try `dataset['ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME'] - dataset['INCIDENT_DATE_TIME']` instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).